# How to represent in UML that one class calls another class method when publishing spring event

Tags: java, spring, events, uml, class-diagram

I want to draw UML diagram which represents my Spring boot application. I'm new in UML and don't know how to represent an interaction between two classes that uses other classes for it. I have a class that publishes spring events and a class which handles such events. Publisher example:

```
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
    
    class Publisher {
    ApplicationEventPublisher springPublisher;
    
    public publishEvent() {
    springPublisher.publishEvent(new SomeEvent());
    }

}
```

Handler:

```
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
  
 class EventHandler {
    @EventListener
    public handleEvent(Event event) {
    // some processing
    }
}
```

So, when I publish some events via Spring ApplicationEventPublisher my handler handles events via method annotated with @EventListener. But it is not a direct calling of the method. How I can illustrate it on the UML diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The class diagram

As [qwerty_so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65127857/3723423) rightly pointed out,  in a class diagram, we do not represent interactions: we represent structure, such as classes, association between classes, and dependencies:

- On the `EventHandler` side, you have a dependency to `Event`.  Since it's an [`@EventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html), `Event` is probably an [`ApplicationEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html)
- On the `Publisher` side, your code has a dependency to `SomeEvent`.  Since it's an [`ApplicationEventPublisher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html),  `SomeEvent` is probably an [`ApplicationEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html).

You may therefore want to show a dependency to the common `ApplicationEvent`:

[image]

### The Spring magic

I'm not a Spring expert, but I understand that [behind the "spring magic" is the annotation](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-application-events-explained/) which hides an automatic registration of the listener to publisher, based on the signature of the annotated method.

You could be tempted to show in your model the (automatic) association between the listener and the publisher.  But IMHO,  this would not reflect well your design, since your model would hardwire the magic, whereas your code is dynamic in this regard.  This is why the simpler diagram I show above, seems more appropriate:  the magic is caused by the common Event denominator.  Just use the right intermetiary type.

### The interactions

If you want to show the dynamics of the interactions, it's a little more complex.  You could for example use an sequence diagram, and encabulate the magic in a `:SpringFramework` lifeline,  and materialize the automatic registration with messages sent to this "virtual" lifeline. Moreover:

- Event sending would then be a message from the publisher to the framework,
- Event listening would be a message sent by the framework to one or several listener.

It's not the real details.  But the readers of your diagram do not need to know these details (except if they'd belong to the spring development team).  So keep it as simple as possible,  but not more :-)

Comment: You must somehow have access to a time machine to produce all these answers :-)

Comment: @qwerty_so you made my day :-)

Comment: I don't agree with the answer : it helps a lot to understand an architecture if methods are linked with dashed lines (for dependency) in a class diagram. Unfortunately a lot of people discourage to do that and purpose sequence diagram instead (which doesn't give any context of what the class contains...)

Comment: @kingsjester You may use usage dependencies, and in particular `«Call»` dependencies that the standard UML profile offers to show a dependency from an operation to another operation that is called. But there are several consequences: 1) you’ll show an implementation dependency, which is a quite detailed level; 2) you might therefor clutter the diagram with a lot of extra dependencies and make it difficult to read; 3) if the dependency would be conditional you’d add to the complexity by requuring additional contraints; 4)the full logic would remain unclear:there is no order between dependencies

Comment: as said, in this specific case it’s better not to hardwire the “magic” since the design would nonlonger take advantage of the flexibility and decoupling offered bu the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You use either an activity or in this case probably better a sequence diagram. Those show behavior. In the SD draw a message arrow from `Publisher` to `Eventhandler` instances (life lines) and label it with the operation `handleEvent()`.

A class diagram only shows static constructs.

Answer (score 0):

It helps a lot to understand an architecture if methods are linked in a class diagram. You can do that with a dashed line and write <<use>> on it. Of course, if the architecture is complex, you won't be able to represent all these associations.

Unfortunately a lot of people discourage to do that and purpose sequence diagram instead (which doesn't give any context of what the class contains...). Furthermore, a lot of software to represent UML class diagrams doesn't work very well to link methods together.